# Stack Overflow questions hijacked by Zescience

Tags: discussion, support, legal, copycat-sites

I just have written a question on Stack Overflow, which [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361406/model-first-entity-framework-max-string-length-of-4000)

Desperately doing more research, I found out that my question was copied to another place, which used to be found at `http://www.zescience.com/model-first-entity-framework-max-string-length-of-4000-197602`.

Is this according to the rules that Stack Overflow has?

Can any of my questions be copied anywhere? I see that I do not have special rights to the source code that I leave on that page, but plain copying is another level.

Comment: Meta.stackexchange post about this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers

Comment: Basically, there's nothing you / SE can do.

Comment: @Cerbrus - not quite. That site doesn't follow our attribution requirements.

Comment: From your link, the hijacking site should give an indication that this question is from stackoverflow. They just copy, there is no way to find out that it was originally asked on SO. Will SO regulate that thing?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers

Comment: Clicking on view answers does redirect to the SO question

Comment: Today I learned... ^

Comment: @Spokey - that's far from clearly attributing. I don't see the name of the OP on the page either.

Comment: Looking at a random short sample of the "questions" on that site they **all** seem to point back to SO for the answers without any attribution on the questions.

Comment: This isn't the first time that I have seen this happen. I have had several instances myself where my questions is mirrored on a site not owned by Stack Exchange. Apparently this is normal and Stack Exchange allows this.

Comment: SE is always going to be more popular than copy pastes, so there's not really a problem. But otherwise this is the internet, stuff cannot and should not be censored.

Comment: Zescience.com has already been reported to SE staff, which noted that taking appropriate action "is often a long and arduous process. You may not see immediate results. However, rest assured that we're working on it."

Comment: @Izkata Well, they had a database issue yesterday. Perhaps they had to scale due to increased click rates. But right now, everything loads, despite is *should* not load.

Comment: A related issue on meta SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274531/zeering-com-profiting-from-so?cb=1 (By the way, most of these site names seem to start with Z. Is this common?)

Comment: Why are you so worried about someone posting your question on their site?

Comment: @NewWorld I am okay that Stackoverflow has my question. We have some kind of contract in the form of "I post a question, the community can provide answers". Some kind of "You help me, I help you" thing. It is okay for me that StackOverflow makes money from this. They have put a beautiful site together. And I do not have any contract with Zescience. They use the content I wrote to make money from it and I cannot expect to get anything back. And it not copied in form like "Hey, look at this interesting question". It is plain copied by a program to generate lots of content. This is not okay.

Comment: @MareInfinitus Yet it doesn't affect you in any way whatsoever, so why let it bother you? And why do you expect payment in exchange for publishing your questions? You got an answer; isn't that enough for you?

Comment: Now it's here: http://widequestion.com/question/entity-framework-model-first-using-ntext-to-get-around-4000-chars-length-limit/

Answer (score 30):

There are a lot of sites which just reproduce SO. You could quibble with them if they don't comply with the SE CC licence; maybe make a DMCA request to their hosting company if they are hosted in the US, but it's probably not worth it.

If you're worried about people making money off your content: SO is already doing that.

Comment: Regarding the money-making, that's a lot thornier than you make it out to be.  I have an existing relationship with StackOverflow, I am okay with them getting something out of the relationship, and I was (at least vaguely) aware of the value exchange betewen us when I signed up, but not with some random third party hijacking my (or rather, our) content.

Comment: For what it's worth, the registrant appears to be from Georgia (the counbtry, not the US State) but the registration is with GoDaddy who might, in an ideal world, have an AUP that they actually enforce.  Hosting is behind CloudFlare who apparently make a point of not policing their customers, so not a lot of hope there.

Comment: Although I have been fully aware for a long time that Stack Exchange makes money off of the content we post, how exactly do they do about doing it? That is something I am unsure of.

Comment: @DavidB the content we contribute makes SE sites popular places to visit, and then [these things happen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model). It's somewhat indirect...

Comment: this site copyed stackoverflow www.guj.com.br

Comment: @user3632930 You may want to create a separate meta post about that as well.

Comment: Btw. everyone is allowed to make money out of the content here. You just have to give attribution and you don't even have to link to SO.

Comment: @tripleee If you're not okay with some random third party making money of the content you post on SO, then you have only one option: *don't post on SO*. Otherwise, read the terms of the [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license, under which all user content on SO is licensed.

Comment: @svick true enough BUT you as well as SO have to be attributed. This is not a matter of making money but of giving tribute to the right person. And following the CC-BY-SA this has to be done. Afterall the "intelectuel" property still belongs to you, you just agreed that anybody can use it for free as long as they atribute it to you.

Answer (score 18):

Other sites are allowed to reproduce content from Stack Exchange as long as they follow [the rules](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). As others point out, this one isn't.

It's reproducing your content, to which [you own the copyright](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228386), without giving you attribution. As such, you could report them yourself (probably to their registrar, GoDaddy).

It would probably be simpler, though, for you to [report them to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177), who have a legal team which can follow this up.

Of course, there's nothing stopping you doing both.