# Zeering.com profiting from Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I previously had  a problem in a homework programming task I am doing, so I copied and pasted the error into Google.

This [link showed up](http://zeering.com/Answer.aspx?q=C%20%20%20function%20pointer%20(class%20member)%20to%20non-static%20member%20function&i=27811), which embeds the entire Stack Overflow page for that question within their website.

Yes, they keep the copyright:
[image]

But they also say `©2014 Zeering.Com`, which obviously refers to their own site, but couldn't it also be claiming that they own the content in the iframe (the Stack Overflow question)?

But (the most important bit!), they seem to be making money from advertisements placed on their page, which of course is unfair since Stack Exchange gets nothing from it! 
Surely making a profit from content on Stack Exchange sites that they do not own is strictly prohibited?

Is this site within the [terms and conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractual_term) of Stack Exchange? The vast majority of this content is from Stack Overflow!

I was interested whether Zeering does the same thing with the content from other Stack Exchange sites, and so far I've only been able to find results from Stack Overflow (wanted to move this question to Stack Exchange Meta, but there's no point if only Stack Overflow is affected by this).

Every link I've visited on this site via its search feature are frames with Stack Overflow questions in them. This seems to be a search engine exclusively for Stack Overflow questions.

**Edit:** The embedding of Stack Overflow via `frame`s has been resolved by Stack Exchange's legal team, however **Zeering.com are *still* not attributing to Stack Exchange's T&C**.

Comment: The even reroute the links on the imbeded page, though [some of the links](http://zeering.com/tour) don't work

Comment: @gunr2171 I saw that. If they did this to my site I would force them to take the content down.

Comment: There seem to be many such sites. Oh well... Copying content is the sincerest form of flattery.

Comment: @MrLister Yes, but this one has taken it to a whole new level.

Comment: They keep the SO logo at least... But they're still profiting off it!

Comment: @MrLister A moderator added the [tag:copycat-sites], when this website **isn't a copycat-site**. The issue with this site is that it is profiting from advertising above the SO embedded frames, and also appears to be entirely dedicated to searching SO questions.

Comment: Well, I am sure any downvotes mostly result in the horrible format of the question. I just edited it and remove all unnecessary bold and cursive formatting or caps. Please refrain from overusing these formatting options, it looks like screaming on the internet. Also, you might want to modify your question to make it more into a question and less statements (e.g. "which of cause is unfair since Stack Exchange gets nothing from it!" is just not necessary and also untrue, as some answers already explained).

Comment: I just get redirected to SO directly when I click on your link (Mozilla SeaMonkey (UbuntuZilla built) on Debian Wheezy)

Comment: @msrd0 The SE legal team contacted them and they were forced to redirect to SO directly rather than embed its pages in frames on their pages. Although this is a good change, they *still haven't put attribution that the content is from Stack Overflow*.

Comment: Well [this](http://i.imgur.com/k3vQ0KF.png) image says all

Answer (score 88, accepted):

zeering.com has been dealt with for now.  Thanks for the report and we'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: They are still quoting questions verbatim without attribution to either the OP or SO. "Show answer in New Window" link goes to SO. See http://zeering.com/LoadAnswers.aspx?q=PHP for examples.

Comment: @DavidPostill So it's basically a Search website for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Looks like the staff dealt with it by ignoring requests (probably a firewall rule?) from zeering.com. Nice.

Comment: "Has been dealt with" - that doesn't sound ominous _at all_...

Comment: @user314104 The site's (and the questions appearing on it) still accessible from my end, perhaps Zeering.com got wind of the block and are actively circumventing it. If so, it could lead to even more trouble..

Comment: @cybermonkey Is correct, this morning I was getting some ASP.NET exception page thrown at me about not being able to open a HTML request, this afternoon, it's showing me content. The answers seem to have no attribution on them.

Comment: They are now redirecting to us after doing their own search.  This is still a violation of our attribution requirements.  We have stopped the worst part where our site was being scraped and embedded in theirs.

Comment: Looks like they are back up and doing it again in a similar fashion. If you click on a link it goes to us; but they still paste the 'text content' of the q & a into their page without attribution.

Comment: @UpAndAdam Their Facebook page (https://www.facebook.com/zeering?ref=ts&fref=ts) suggests that the current Zeering.com was a file sharing site previously, but was 'recycled' by its owner.

Comment: You may want to check this too stoflru.org with attribution whatsoever.

Comment: @Omar Ouch! Unsure if they're directly scraping content from Stack Overflow, or just an independent site. If they're an independent site, there's nothing that can be done because technically the site isn't doing anything wrong.

Comment: @Omar They've been caught: http://stoflru.org/questions/25191498/using-sleep-in-vb-net-while-running-external-process is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191498/using-sleep-in-vb-net-while-running-external-process. Will report that in a couple of hours when I'm free.

Comment: @cybermonkey they're scraping and translating with no attribution whatsoever.

Comment: @Omar http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274857/another-stack-overflow-clone-but-with-a-twist

Comment: @GeoffDalgas this is still happening, without attribution - http://mvc.zeering.com/LoadAnswers.aspx?q=Clean-e-commerce-app-with-user-friendly-non-techie-proof-admin-interface-.

Answer (score 49):

> they seem to be making money from advertisements placed on their page, which of cause is unfair since Stack Exchange gets NOTHING from it! Surely making a profit from content on SE sites that they do not own is strictly prohibited?

> Is this site keeping within the T&C of SE (probably not!)?

> It's definitely not ok to make money from content they do not own

You seem to be under the impression that reproducing Q/A content from SO (or other SE sites) for profit is not allowed. This is not true. The Creative Commons license for all user-submitted content requires *attribution* (and keeping the content under the same terms) but it absolutely does not forbid profit.

Comment: Yes, but the Stack Exchange T&C **doesn't allow third-party sites to profit from the content of SE sites**. I'm happy that SE makes money from my questions, answers, comments, etc, they deserve to because they made such a great Q&A platform.

Comment: @cybermonkey There is no such prohibition. It would go against the CC BY-SA license. Anyone is allowed to reuse the content of SO, given proper attribution. (Reusing SO's name and logo, on the other hand, is prohibited under trade mark law.)

Comment: @Gilles True, but given that the Stack Exchange staff are investigating the issue, sounds like they're investigating it because of the adverts above the embedded SO page,

Comment: @cybermonkey I can't speak for Stack Exchange, but my guess is that the adverts are not the main issue.

Comment: @svick Perhaps not, it'll probably be the `iframe` embedding of the entire site.

Comment: Guys, you don't seem to get it: This is not bad, this is awesome. I'm just happy that the content gets copied and distributed. I don't work for stackoverflow. If any other site distributes my work they deserve the profit, and of course the product of my work I give for free to the general community of programmers who freely share so much knowledge with me, not the stack exchange community per se.

Comment: @elcodedocle No. Leaving all copyright aside, I find this copying annoying as there's no use for anyone (except them). Instead of landing on SO where you'd get more answers and the community, you land on some stupid copy. Instead of a single search result, you have to deal with multiple identical ones. If they added any value, e.g., a better search or whatever...

Comment: If it's just a copy I doubt very much it competes with SO in any way. You'll end up in SO because search engines are built like that. Or you'll figure it out by yourself, if you have to. Competitors are good and help the site to thrive and get better. Even bad competitors are good. If it's a useless site, why care?  It'll fade away by itself. There's no downside, and in this particular case no threat to SO's business.

Comment: From a resource management point of view they should probably block sites embedding their content to avoid having to deal with the extra traffic, but I'm not even sure they should do that because in the end they are promoting SO, and most of their users will end up here, were the fresh answers are cooked and delivered hot... Who wants to be fed stale content?

Comment: The way in which this annoys me is that it basically adds noise to search results. There's really no logical reason for us to have this duplication on the internet. The only people who benefit are the guys raking in the ad cash.

Answer (score 35):

Here's a few important points about this site and similar sites:

1. This site was certainly doing something wrong if the Stack Exchange team felt it necessary that they be "dealt with" -- in this answer I'll explore what that wrongdoing might have been.
2. There's **absolutely nothing wrong** with making money by re-posting *user-submitted content* from Stack Exchange sites (not the *entire site content*, though; see the first bullet point below). All users agree to license their submissions under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike (cc-by-sa) license, which does not discriminate based on commercial use (unlike cc-by-nc, for example). In the general case, there is no need to be alarmed that someone is re-posting questions and answers from Stack Exchange.
3. While re-posting is okay in the general case, there are a few specific cases (that, again, you should note have *nothing* to do with commercial use; I cannot stress this enough) where people tend to go wrong, however:

- re-posting [non-user-submitted "network content"](https://stackexchange.com/legal#2NetworkContent) (i.e., everything *except* the questions and answers submitted by users) like the site logo, icons, HTML, CSS, etc. Any kind of iframe embedding (which appears to have happened here originally) is likely to violate this restriction -- *especially* because Stack Exchange [doesn't allow direct iframe embedding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103405/should-stack-exchange-be-using-the-x-frame-options-header) (via `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`), so the site must have run the content through a same-origin proxy, meaning that the site itself was hosting Stack Exchange's network content.
- failure to satisfy Stack Exchange's [attribution requirements](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/): mentioning Stack Exchange by name, including original user names and profile links, and linking back to the original post without `rel="nofollow"`. As of this edit, they're currently still not following this requirement, as I don't see a single author name anywhere on the site.

Again, there are important rules to follow when re-posting Stack Exchange questions and answers (which it seems were not followed by this site), but understand that none of those rules have any bearing on the for-profit status of the site re-posting the content. A site that is proudly not-for-profit can run afoul of these rules just as easily as a for-profit site.

That said, you are certainly correct to be alarmed to see an *entire* Stack Exchange site reproduced elsewhere, whether or not the reproduction is done to make a profit. Such a total reproduction certainly violates the use restrictions on network content.

(The prevailing business wisdom behind sharing *user content* is that a copycat site that mindlessly scrapes content will never be as popular as a site that *generates* content; meanwhile, the freedom to re-post Q&As from Stack Exchange broadens the reach of users' shared knowledge.)

Comment: They were not reposting content, they were putting the Stack Overflow site in a iframe, that is to say **they were embedding the site**, including use of all logos and images of SE and SO. For this reason, *this site isn't a copycat site*. They also weren't just reposting questions, they were **reposing the entire SO site**.

Comment: @cybermonkey iframe embedding certainly sounds like a misuse of network content, as described in my second bullet point. I'll edit my answer to highlight that likely possibility.

Comment: FYI they are back up.

Comment: @cybermonkey the site is back up, but I don't see any iframes. Is the site different now from when you first found it (e.g., maybe they made some changes after SE legal contacted them), or am I looking in the wrong places? Note that even as-is, it's still an issue because they don't follow attribution requirements.

Comment: @apsillers Correct, but however there's *still* not attribution...

Comment: "The prevailing business wisdom behind sharing user content" - It also comes from the content license. With a CC license you basically have no chance to keep the content as exclusive content. Why Stack Exchange has chosen such a license? I guess because they thought that otherwise they would not get enough contributors. But this also includes that at any time someone could come up with a better version of presenting and running the content. Bascially the competition to present the free content in the best possible way is absolutely open.