# Another Stack Overflow clone, but with a twist

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites, portuguese-stack-overflow, stack-exchange

I was looking at the new comments/votes on my [Meta question about a similar site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274531/zeering-com-profiting-from-stack-overflow), and @Omar [commented with yet another site that's blatantly scraping content from Stack Overflow](http://stoflru.org), but with a twist.

**The twist? *The site's in Russian***.

It's obvious that `stoflru` could translate to `st` (Stack) `ofl` (Overflow), `ru` (Russian), but they're still breaking the Creative-Commons license that Stack Exchange uses, and they're also not attributing:

[image]

*The question in the screenshot is [here on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191498/using-sleep-in-vb-net-while-running-external-process)*

When browsing the site I cannot find any way to register or log into the site, suggesting that the website's just a proxy that translates all text in the main body of the page into Russian, and *indeed, the site is blocked on my work network as `security.proxy`*:

[image]

It also appears that the last time `stoflru` scraped content from Stack Overflow was August 7th, so perhaps this site has already been dealt with by the Stack Exchange legal team?

I personally like the idea that Stack Overflow should be available in more languages (other than English and Portuguese), but such a request should be upheld with the Stack Exchange team (and probably likely on Area 51) than a 'do whatever and see what happens` approach.

There's also the issue of the advertisements on the website.

Comment: Regarding SO in other languages, there's a list of proposals here: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/1235/108893

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers

Comment: Just as a comment, the automatic translation is _hilariously bad_. Might read the site just for a laugh.

Comment: Also, pages contain a link back to the original SO answer, "источник" ("source") in the right column.

Comment: NOT A DUPLICATE: My other question relates to a site that displayed Stack Overflow content in a frame, this one does not.

Comment: [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?act=url&depth=1&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&sl=en&tl=ru&u=http://stackoverflow.com/) is probably not worse.

Comment: @cybermonkey http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers Just report it through the contact us link, no need to start a discussion about it.