# StackExchange clone website

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

[This](http://www.kexcheta.club/) website looks like a clone of StackExchange. Is it bad?

Comment: Looks more like a mirror to me. Strange, if you click on a site to which you are logged in, you're redirected to the official Stack Exchange site. Otherwise, you get a static mirror. Not sure what their motivation would be for doing this, they don't get the ad revenue.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do

Comment: I've reported it to SE, as per the guide. Next time you see something like this, you can just use the "Contact us" form, as the link in Mureinik's comment describes.

Comment: @CodyGray China apparently blocks the Stack Exchange network, so it could be an attempt by Chinese users to access the Network. Similar to [stoflru](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274857/another-stack-overflow-clone-but-with-a-twist).